# Document transformation based type

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have a mongodb document

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "types" : ["online" ,"offline"],
  "applications" : [ ["online", "online"], ["offline"] ]
}
```

I would like to transformed into

```
{
"id" : 1,
"types" : [
        {
          "type" : "online",
          "count" : 2,
          "applications" : [ "online", "online"]
        },
        {
          "type" : "offline",
          "count" : 1,
          "applications" : [ "offline" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

here types and applications arrays can be of any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in two steps, use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to match `type` with `applications` and then run [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to get `count`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            id: 1,
            types: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$types",
                    as: "type",
                    in: {
                        type: "$$type",
                        applications: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$applications",
                                as: "application",
                                cond: { 
                                    $allElementsTrue: {
                                        $map: { input: "$$application", in: { $eq: [ "$$this", "$$type" ] } }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            types: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$types",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$this",
                            { 
                                count: { 
                                    $reduce: { 
                                        input: "$$this.applications", 
                                        initialValue: 0, 
                                        in: { $add: [ "$$value", { $size: "$$this" }  ] } 
                                    }
                                } 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

You can decide whether it's better to use [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/index.html) or [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) when building your filtering criteria.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iEA1iBnhmSa)